# My javascript hides all the divs.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So, Here is my little barter calculator.

The problem is that when I try to add it to my site it goes all nuts by hiding all the divs. (It literally applies display:none to all of them).

How can I make this work?

Additionaly, I would like to make the script calculate value after pressing Submit button, not dynamically like now. Any easy way to do it?

It goes like this(sample, for full code go to jsfiddle, link at the bottom):

```
<div id="Apple">
    <ul>
        <li><span data-val="2"></span> bananas</li>
        <li><span data-val="3"></span> oranges</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And this is my JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function showTab(name) {
        $('div').hide();
        var $div = $('#' + name).show();
        var number = parseInt($('.number').val(), 0);
        $('span', $div).each(function() {
            $(this).text($(this).data('val') * number);
        });
    }

    $('#dropdown').change(function () {
        showTab($(this).val());
    });

    showTab($('#dropdown').val());
});
```

[**Fiddle - check it live**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/2A5Xx/3/)

Comment: You are using `$('div').hide();` thus its hiding all div

Comment: Well what do you expect `$('div').hide();` to do?

Answer (score 4):

Analyse the code carefully. The `showTab()` function hides **all** divs on your site:

```
$('div').hide();
```

And then it shows the one which matches your tab:

```
var $div = $('#' + name).show();
```

You'll need to change the first selector to something a little more specific to your own markup, otherwise it will continue to hide other `<div>` elements. Unfortunately, it's not clear what structure you're using based on the Fiddle, so I can't help more.

I'd recommend adding a class to the numerous sections, and then updating your code. For the `#Apple` example:

```
<div id="Apple" class="tab">
```

In turn, you can then use the selector:

```
$('div.tab').hide();
```

It might be better to also use jQuery's [`not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) function, to create some exclusivity as follows:

```
$('div.tab').not('#'+name).hide();
```

This will also eliminate the need to later call `show()`.

Comment: Thank you, this does seem to work. I can't believe I missed it.
How can I make the result show up after pressing submit button?

Comment: @AndyAndy, that's a separate question ;)

Answer (score 2):

`$('div').hide();` will hide every div on the page. Be more specific:

```
$('div.fruit').hide();
```

---

```
<div id="Apple" class="fruit">
    <ul>
        <li><span data-val="2"></span> bananas</li>
        <li><span data-val="3"></span> oranges</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2A5Xx/4/)

Answer (score 0):

you have `$('div').hide();` - no wonder all divs are hidden, maybe you should narrow it down with some `$('#container div').hide();` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your selector

> $('div').hide();

to

> $('#Apple').hide();

Comment: This won't work if he adds more than one tab, which is what he's trying to do.

Comment: If all your divs have the same class "fruit" you can use $('.fruit').hide();